# Keep or delete proxee.co links to SO?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks

I just discovered a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26977425/2257664) which contained a link to `https://[something].proxee.co` ([here is the edit)](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6252554). The link is:

```
https://http--stackoverflowzx-com.proxee.co/questions/10517452/how-can-i-pass-a-full-security-roles-list-hierarchy-to-a-formtype-class-in-symfo
```

This is only a *anonymized* version of this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10517452/how-can-i-pass-a-full-security-roles-list-hierarchy-to-a-formtype-class-in-symfo
```

There are already 5 questions and one answer which use similar URLs, the oldest post with one of these links is only 3 days old: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*proxee.co%22

And the majority are links to SO: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=url%3A%22*http--stackoverflowzx-com.proxee.co%22

Are these types of links allowed on SO? At this moment it only act as an anonymizer to view the linked page anonymously but it may be used for phishing too (see [Possible Stack Overflow phishing site?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271305/possible-stack-overflow-phishing-site)). And what is the point of anomymizing a link to a website you're already visiting? Can a virus cause this?

Comment: I left comment under one answer and invited the OP to this question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Definitely replace these links with their proper non-redirected equivalent.**

- It may confuse visitors, who will get a logged-out view of stackoverflow
- the proxee service may be discontinued or subverted by malware,
- the service *will* most likely insert ads into the pages,
- The service may be used to phish for stackoverflow passwords
- it breaks stackoverflow link features such as listing a linked question under "related questions".
- and there is absolutely no benefit from leaving these links as they are.

If these links become more frequent, it may warrant adding the domain to the blacklist, or considering automated link-rewrite solutions, but right now that seems overkill.

---

**Some speculations about the reasons for these links:**

I highly doubt these links where added with bad intentions,  but simply by someone using this proxy for themselves when researching references for their question or answer.  They are probably not even aware that the links they copied where altered.

When you use an anonymizing web proxy such as this, it will rewrite each link on each page you visit so it goes to the proxy instead of the real domain. This way you can follow links on a page and stay on the proxy.

This allows someone to browse sites from a network where the site is blocked, or hide their real ip while browsing, or hide their web traffic from censors, etc.

If someone used this proxy to access stackoverflow because of a local block, or to access google and search for stackoverflow questions, or simply uses this proxy for all their surfing, they would get these altered links, and when they copy those links to insert them into their question or answer, you get this result.

Answer (score 7):

There is no way, aside from clicking on the link, to check whether it really goes to a Stack Overflow question. And perhaps you go through some malicious websites before you reach the question. For the same reason, URL shorteners are blocked, so I'd say these types of links should be blocked too.

Comment: OK, thanks. Is there a way to alert the team of SE in order to blacklist this domain name?

Comment: @A.L This question is a good start. If the team doesn't respond here, you can use the "contact" link in the page footer.

Comment: In fact I don't know if SE uses a blacklist or let the users review posts and clean the bad links.

Comment: @A.L Hm, yeah, I'm also not sure about that. Anyway, I don't think there is something wrong with contacting them, they might also have a bot or something that can edit all those links.

Comment: @A.L and ProgramFOX: [Yes, they do blacklist some urls.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255032/should-we-add-it-ebooks-info-to-the-stack-overflow-url-blacklist) Though I'm sure it's rare and the url has to be a real issue...

Answer (score 1):

I posted my first question and linked to a previous question on Stackoverflow. I didn't even notice the address had proxee.co in it!! Thanks to A.L I came to know about it and changed it.
I got the link with proxee in it by searching topics in Google...

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, so this website duplicates the content from SO and Google has indexed these proxee.co pages.